# How can we use find negative number in an array using shift method

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find the `negative` value in an array, once found I would like to break and exit the loop and print the results. While using `shift()` it is printing only upto 3 iteration, could someone please advise about the issue here.

```
let newArr = [100,200,0,400,500,-50,600];

function findNegValue(newArr) {

  for(let i =0; i <= newArr.length ; i++){
      let arrayValue = newArr.shift();
      console.log("EachArrayValues::"+arrayValue);
      if(arrayValue < 0){
      console.log("Negative value found, ie "+arrayValue);
         break;
      } else {
        continue ;
      }
    }
  }
  
  findNegValue(newArr);
```

//Output:

```
EachArrayValues::100
EachArrayValues::200
EachArrayValues::0
EachArrayValues::400
```

// Without shift() it is working fine

```
let newArr = [100,200,0,400,500,-50,600];

function findNegativeNumber(newArr) {

  for(let i =0; i < newArr.length ; i++){
      let arrayValue = newArr[i];
      console.log("len::"+newArr.length);
      console.log("EachArrayValues::"+arrayValue);
      if(arrayValue < 0){
      console.log("Negative value found, ie "+arrayValue);
         break;
      } 
    }
  }
  
  findNegativeNumber(newArr);

len::7
EachArrayValues::100
len::7
EachArrayValues::200
len::7
EachArrayValues::0
len::7
EachArrayValues::400
len::7
EachArrayValues::500
len::7
EachArrayValues::-50
Negative value found, ie -50
```

Comment: Because `shift()` is changing the `newArr.length`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) says:

> The shift() method **removes the first element** from an array **and** **returns that removed element**. This method changes the length of the array.

Each iteration you're accessing the current array element **and** removing the first element. So basically you're skipping half of the elements because each iteration the previous first element was already removed and your `i` variable is being incremented.

To fix that access the array element through `[i]` operator (as you're already doing) or `Array.at` method.

```js
let newArr = [100,200,0,400,500,-50,600];

function findNegativeNumber(newArr) {
  for(let i =0; i < newArr.length ; i++){
    let arrayValue = newArr[i];
    // let arrayValue = newArr.at(i);
    // ...
  }
}
  
findNegativeNumber(newArr);
```

And if you want to use `shift` method then do not use `i` to control the index, just use `shift` with a `while` statement:

```js
let newArr = [100,200,0,400,500,-50,600];

function findNegativeNumber(newArr) {
  while (newArr.length !== 0) {
    let arrayValue = newArr.shift();
    // ...
  }
}
  
findNegativeNumber(newArr);
```

Also there's a shortcut and more elegant solution to find the first negative number of an array:

```js
let newArr = [100,200,0,400,500,-50,600];
let firstNegativeNumber = newArr.find(e => e < 0);
let allNegativeNumbers = newArr.filter(e => e < 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you `shift` your array, it is taking the first value **out of the array**. Hence, `i` is not less than `newArr.length` at half of the length of the original `newArr`.

```js
const myArr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

for (let i = 0; i <= myArr.length; i++) {
  let arrayValue = myArr.shift();
  console.log("by unshift::" + arrayValue);
  console.log("by [i]::    " + myArr[i]);
  console.log("=======");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a while loop to achieve what you are trying to do

```
let newArr = [100,200,0,400,500,-50,600];

  
  while(newArr.length){              
      let arrayValue = newArr.shift();
      console.log("EachArrayValues::"+arrayValue);
      if(arrayValue < 0){
      console.log("Negative value found, ie "+arrayValue);
         break;
      } else {
        continue ;
      }
}
```

Output :

```
EachArrayValues::100
EachArrayValues::200
EachArrayValues::0
EachArrayValues::400
EachArrayValues::500
EachArrayValues::-50
Negative value found, ie -50
```